# Ember - using api/server data

Tags: ember.js

I am new to ember and I like what I see so far. I have done the tutorial and found to to be pretty easy to get something up and running. My question has to do with using mirage vs real data. I used mirage to stub in some data but now I would like to link to to real data. I would think this should not be too hard since I have the models..etc set up I just need to call an api instead of mirage. I have not seen a clean example of how best to do this.

Thanks

Comment: Whats exactly your problem? Just don't use mirage, but call your actual API. For development use the ember proxy `ember s --proxy=http://api`. However ember will not help you to build your API because its a client side framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn mirage on/off for all requests per environment in `config/environment.js` e.g. off for development, on for testing,

```
// config/environment.js

if (environment === 'development') {
  ENV['ember-cli-mirage'] = {
    enabled: false
  };
}

if (environment === 'test') {
  ENV['ember-cli-mirage'] = {
    enabled: true
  };
}
```

Or if you leave mirage on for everything, allow specific endpoints to with `passthrough`:

http://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/docs/v0.3.x/configuration/#passthrough